All sections & plugins gone after local reinstall - help!
I had to reinstall the project locally to solve an issue but now when logging into the admin dashboard locally:

all sections are gone
plugins are gone
fields etc are gone
It shows as Craft Solo instead of Pro
Dashboard shows pending yaml chan
ges. When I try to apply them it doesn't work because of a dodgy plugin from a while back:
Migration Error: An error occurred while executing the "craft\commerce\stripe\migrations\Install migration: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists...

The only thing it seems to have right is the multi sites I have set up in the Sites settings.
As far as I can see the code files are all as they should be and yaml has all the sections etc showing.
Any ideas? I'm more on the design side of things so struggle with databases etc.

Solved it by manually removing the references to it in the yaml file! I then had to apply the yaml changes in the dashboard a few times over before the sections came back. Adjusted the craft cms plan in the yaml file too. There was still a discrepancy between the local and production yaml files so I did a database pull back from production which resolved that.

Feel free to mark this as "The Answer" to close things out :)

That migration error is probably the culprit behind the behavior you're seeing, and it's likely caused by a plugin's install migration attempting to create a table that already exists in your database.
To fix it, make sure the database is completely empty before re-installing your project.

Couldn't get access to the database but solved it by manually removing the references to it in the yaml file!
